# Tell AngularJs to return a new instance via Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The use case is simple: I have two controllers sharing the same dependency `MyService`. This service is holding some state, lets sat `myVariable`. If I set it from `ControllerOne`, then it will be also spotted by `ControllerTwo`.

What I want is for each controller to have it's own instance of `MyService`, so that `myVariable` can be changed by each Controller without affecting the other.

To put it in another words - I want **new instance** to be returned by Dependency Injection, **rather than singleton**.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13620494/215945

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not as directly has you might hope. Service instances are created the first time they're retrieved by the injector and maintained by the injector... in other words, they're always singletons. [The magic happens in here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js), particularly look at the `provider` function, which puts the provider instance in the providerCache object.

But don't lose hope, you could just as easily add constructors for whatever it is you want to share in a Service, if you so chose:

```
app.factory('myService', [function() {
     var i = 1;

     function Foo() {
        this.bar = "I'm Foo " + i++;
     };

     return {
          Foo: Foo
     };
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.foo = new myService.Foo();
  console.log($scope.foo.bar) //I'm Foo 1
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.foo = new myService.Foo();
  console.log($scope.foo.bar) //I'm Foo 2
});
```

EDIT: as the OP pointed out, there is also the [$injector.instantiate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector), which you can use to call JavaScript constructors outside of your controller. I'm not sure what the implications are of the testability here, but it does give you another way to inject code that will construct a new object for you.

Comment: There is also another way. You can simply create an object with needed dependencies (Component X) and then inject it directly with `$injector.instantiate(ComponentX, {})`. The second argument may contain all the `statefull` variables. Easy and elegant, thank you Angular Js! 
Perhaps you could add it to your response as an alternative solution, please?

Comment: Seems to be the solution, but you need to return only the constructor. All other methods you could return aside will never affect any instances you will create later, except if you add them to the prototype of your constructor... See karlgold answer, which is almost perfect.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of general options for modularizing JavaScript code, but if you want to do something that relies solely on AngularJS, this pattern works:

1) First define the class that you want to inject multiple times:

```
function MyClass() {
  // ...
}

MyClass.prototype.memberMethod = function() {
  // ...
}
```

2) Next, make the constructor available as a constant:

```
angular.module('myModule').constant('MyClass', MyClass);
```

3) Finally, use the factory pattern to create named, injectable instances of the class:

```
angular.module('myOtherModule', ['myModule']).factory('instanceOfMyClass', [
   'MyClass', 
   function(MyClass) { return new MyClass(); }
]);
```

Comment: Good idea. But this does not work if your prototype needs injections which cannot be done with constants, neither values... In this case, I guess creating a service is a better option.